# How to get a reference to individual buttons created in a loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, frontend

Attempting to create a book issue page. [image: Page I'm working on]

I get the data (the document variable) displayed as an array of n-ples, and add the borrow/return buttons in the loop with these data fields. However, since I create multiple instances of the same button variable as seen below, I have no way of knowing which one is clicked. Here is the code:

```
document = self.app.Member(MemberVerification.mem_id, self.app).searchDocument(SearchBooks.inputvalues, "Books")
        logger.info("Results: " + str(document) + " for string filters: " + str(filters))
        cells={}
        for i in range(len(document)):  # Rows
            self.borrow = tk.Button(self, text="Borrow", command= lambda: self.checkBorrows(document[i], self.controller, i))
            self.retbook = tk.Button(self, text="Return")
            for j in range(1, len(document[1])):  # Columns
                try:
                    b = tk.Entry(self,justify=tk.CENTER)
                    b.grid(row=i, column=j)
                    b.insert(tk.END, str(document[i][j]))
                    cells[(i, j)] = b
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error("Error in populateTable: " + str(e) + traceback.format_exc())
                    sys.exit(-1)
            if i!=0:
                self.borrow.grid(row=i, column=j+1)
                self.borrowbuttons.append(self.borrow)
                self.retbook.grid(row=i, column=j+2)
```

A little explanation - `i == 0` is where the column names come in. The button in question is `self.borrow`. I tried maintaining a list of them to search which button it is, but that didn't work. I would like to be able to maintain a reference to the specific button out of the 3 that have been created, so that the callback function `checkBorrows` can know which book has to be borrowed. The `i` parameter was just experimentation, doesn't seem to pass the index in due to the async nature of the button click listener

Any suggestions? I tried maintaining a class variable, but that always ends up referring to the last button, since the callback is technically async.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered saving them in a list or dictionary?

Comment: Change `lambda: self.checkBorrows(...)` to `lambda i=i: self.checkBorrows(...)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have borrowbuttons as a list to store all of them, need a way to pass which actual button is clicked to the callback

Comment: @acw1668 this worked! Thanks! Can you explain what the lambda i=i did?

Comment: In your original code, you reference `i` when calling `self.checkBorrows(...)`.  When the function is being executed, `i` will be the last value after the for loop.  However, using `lambda i=i: ...`, it assigns the current value of `i` variable of the for loop to the lambda argument `i` and in this case, when `self.checkBorrows(...)` is executed, it references the argument `i` of the lambda instead of the `i` variable of the for loop.